# temperature converter not giving output

Tags: iphone

i have written a code for temperature conversion for iphone but it is not working and neither giving any error please help

**interface section**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

float n ;
float k;



@interface farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    UILabel *display;
    IBOutlet UITextField *farhenite;
    IBOutlet UIButton *convert;

}


-(IBAction) convert; 


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *display;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *farhenite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *convert;
@end
```

**implementation section**

```
#import "farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate.h"


@implementation farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate


@synthesize window,display,farhenite;





-(IBAction) convert  {

    NSString *str = [NSString text];

    float n = [str floatValue];


      k = (n - 32)*(5/9);



    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];  

}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: Please, format your code section so they display properly!

Comment: What is i in [NSString i];, i not declare any where.

Comment: NSString *str = [NSString i]; What is 'i'?

Comment: what is the problem?????

Comment: @ chetan Bhalara    @ iphonepgr sry that is not i it is text i first printed it wrong

Comment: are you sure there are no errors when you compile your code?

Comment: @jv42  yes it compiles but does not give an output when i put a value

Comment: what the out put of [NSString text];?

Comment: @lukya  yes i have checked repeatedly  there are no errors.

Comment: @Junior Bill gates Where is the text declared?

Comment: @iphonepgr should it be declared first ? if yes where should i declare it

Comment: which value you want to convert farhenite?

Comment: @ chetan bhalara i want to enter a value entered in simulator and then want to convert it to celcius

Comment: @Junior Bill gates Is text is the value to be converted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert the value entered in textField you the method should be like this

```
-(IBAction) convert  {

    NSString *str = yourTextField.text; // In your case farhenite i guess

    float n = [str floatValue];


      k = (n - 32)*(5/9);



    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];  

}
```

Comment: @7kv7 NSString *str = yourTextField.text; what this line of code performs?

Comment: its for obtaining the text from the textfield you have. In your case it should be the name of your textfield which i think is farhenite

Comment: @7kv7  now if i enter a value in simulator it is not coming into *str and the value of n remains 0

Comment: @7kv7 if i out the str on the iphone simulator it displays (null)

Comment: nslog your textfield.text value.

Comment: Or try this float n = [textfield.text floatValue];

Comment: @ 7kv7 if i enter a value in simulator then it also not comes in farhenite.text

Comment: u have to enter the value in the textfield only then u can do this. Make sure you connect the iboutlets

Comment: @ 7kv7 i have checked everything but the same problem still persists i.e when i enter a value it does not come into farhenite.text

Answer (score 1):

if you wan to convert from textfield then it should be

```
NSString *str = textField.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your function with below function.
Than it will work fine.

-(IBAction) convert  {

```
NSString *str = display.text;

float n = [str floatValue];


  k = (n - 32)*(5/9);



[display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you Want to Convert the value from the farhenite text field,then it should be

```
-(IBAction) convert  {

    NSString *str = farhenite.text;

    float n = [str floatValue];


      k = (n - 32)*(5/9);



    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];  

}
```

Comment: @ iphone pgr  now if i enter a value in simulator it is not coming into *str and the value of n remains 0

Comment: @ iphonepgr  yes i connected iboutlet

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = display.text;
```

Just replace the str declaration.