# Check for blocking a string in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have made a Fahrenheit to Celcius converter. I want to block a string so that it is not taken by iPhone as input.

```
#import "farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate.h"

@implementation farh_celcius_conv_AppDelegate
@synthesize window,display,farhenite;

-(IBAction) convert {
    NSString *str = [NSString text];
    float n = [str floatValue];
    k = (n - 32)*(5/9);
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];  
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean, block a String? Do you mean you wish to *read* a String?

Comment: @ pal brattberg sir i mean that it should not produce any output when i enter any string (like hfeiou). now if i enter such string it produces an arbitrary output

Comment: You only want output when the string is actually a valid number?

Comment: @ pal brattberg yes i want an output only when an integer type number is entered

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962153/temperature-converter-not-giving-output/5962477#5962477

Comment: Se updated answer, and if you only want for integer, use `[strintValue]` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after parsing the question, here's another answer.

Replace:

```
k = (n - 32)*(5/9);
[display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];
```

With:

```
if (n != 0) {
  k = (n - 32)*(5/9);
  [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",k]];  
}
```

Comment: @ pal brattberg  if (k != 0) { here we have to use n instead of k i.e if( n != 0) } rest it worked thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @ pal brattberg sir is it possible in iphone to use same field as input and output. for e.g can we use label both as display and textfield.

Comment: Ah, true. My bad (I have updated code). Sure you could change the contents of your `UITextField` to the result, but it might be quite confusing for the user. If you decide to try this, just call `setText`  on the same text field where you get your initial value from.